# How to set value to NULL in editable QTableView with QSqlTableModel

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

I have a `QTableView` that displays subset of the data from a table in SQLite database. The table is editable only for nullable numeric columns. I created two delegates - one for read-only columns:

```
class ReadOnlyDelegate(QtWidgets.QItemDelegate):
    def editorEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return False

    def createEditor(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return None
```

and one for editable columns:

```
class LabelDelegate(QtWidgets.QItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, options, index):
        self.le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent)
        return self.le
```

The table is fed by customized `QSqlTableModel`, where I overwrite submitAll method:

```
class MySqlTableModel(QtSql.QSqlTableModel):
    def submitAll(self):
        for row in range(self.rowCount()):
            for col in range(self.columnCount()):
                if self.isDirty(self.index(row, col)):
                    val = self.record(row).value(col)
                    if val == '':
                        self.record(row).setNull(col)
                    else:
                        try:
                            self.record(row).setValue(col, float(val))
                        except (TypeError, ValueError):
                            display_error_msg('Can not convert to float',
                                              f'The value {val} could not be converted to float')
                            raise
        super().submitAll()
```

Expected behaviour is (1) to convert values to float before sending to database, (2) reject inputs that can't be converted to float and (3) to convert empty string to NULL. (1) and (2) work as expected, however the last bit is not working. When debugging method `.submitAll()` it raises no exception on the line `self.record(row).setNull(col)` but it also seems to have no effect. An empty string is sent and persisted in database. Any ideas why and how to fix it?

Comment: [QSqlTableModel.record](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#record-1) is `const`. You need to use [setRecord](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#setRecord).

Comment: I'll give it a try, but `self.record(row).setValue(col, float(val))` works. It's just that `self.record(row).setNull(col)` does not set value to `NULL` but an empty string. Acctually I incorrectly stated that it seems to have no effect. It also works, just setting value to empty string. If I edit a record by removing a numeric entry it is persisted in database, but as empty string rather than `NULL`.

Comment: This could be specific to SQLite, because it doesn't have "real" data types. You can insert any data type to any column. I don't run into this problem elsewhere, because I'm using sqlalchemy which takes care of that. On other backends it wouldn't be possible to insert string into numeric column.

Comment: I never use records to set values, so I just assumed `setRcord` would be necessary since several other Qt APIs work that way. Have you tried `setValue(col, None)`?

Comment: Yes, but the result is exactly the same as with `setNull`

Comment: @MJB please provide a [mre], and shows the command that creates the table

Comment: Do you have the same problem in pyqt5 and pyside2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the need to override the `submitAll()` method, instead you can implement the logic in the `setModelData()` method:

```py
import sys

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtSql

TABLENAME = "t1"


def create_connection():
    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName("database.db")
    if not db.open():
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.critical(
            None,
            QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().tr("Cannot open database"),
            QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().tr(
                "Unable to establish a database connection.\n"
                "This example needs SQLite support. Please read "
                "the Qt SQL driver documentation for information "
                "how to build it.\n\n"
                "Click Cancel to exit."
            ),
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel,
        )
        return False

    if TABLENAME in db.tables():
        return True

    query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
    if not query.exec_(f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {TABLENAME}(a REAL, b text);"):
        print(query.lastError().text())

    queries = (
        f"INSERT INTO {TABLENAME} VALUES(1, '1');",
        f"INSERT INTO {TABLENAME} VALUES(NULL, '2');",
        f"INSERT INTO {TABLENAME} VALUES(3, '3');",
        f"INSERT INTO {TABLENAME} VALUES(NULL, '4');",
        f"INSERT INTO {TABLENAME} VALUES(5, '4');",
        f"INSERT INTO {TABLENAME} VALUES(NULL, '5');",
        f"INSERT INTO {TABLENAME} VALUES(NULL, '7');",
    )

    for query in queries:
        q = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
        if not q.exec_(query):
            print(q.lastError().text(), query)
            return False

    return True


class ReadOnlyDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def editorEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return False

    def createEditor(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return None


class LabelDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, options, index):
        le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(parent)
        return le

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        value = editor.text()
        if not value:
            model.setData(index, None, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
        else:
            try:
                number = float(value)
            except (TypeError, ValueError):
                print(
                    f"Can not convert to float, The value {value} could not be converted to float'"
                )
            else:
                model.setData(index, number, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)


def main(args):
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(args)

    if not create_connection():
        sys.exit(-1)

    view = QtWidgets.QTableView()

    model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
    model.setTable(TABLENAME)
    model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
    model.select()

    view.setModel(model)

    label_delegate = LabelDelegate(view)
    view.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, label_delegate)

    readonly_delegate = ReadOnlyDelegate(view)
    view.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, readonly_delegate)

    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Submit all")

    widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(widget)
    lay.addWidget(button)
    lay.addWidget(view)

    widget.resize(640, 480)
    widget.show()

    button.clicked.connect(model.submitAll)

    ret = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(ret)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Tested on Linux with:

- PyQt5 5.15.4
- PySide2 5.15.2
- Python 3.9.4